# Using sed on *nix with a regular expression to update a file

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to remove some extra caching data within HTML files.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/built/screen.css?v=7c55ebffcc" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/built/screen.css%3Fv=b45eadba8e.css" />
```

I want to remove the *?v=7c55ebffcc* and the *%3Fv=b45eadba8e.css* from the file. I wrote a regular expression that finds the items I want to replace: `(?<=css)([\?%3F]).*(?=")`

However, I can't see to get the regular expression to work with find. This is the command I'm running:

`find ./build -type f -exec sed -i '' -e 's/(?<=css)([\?%3F]).*(?=")//g' {} +`

Any suggestions to what I'm missing or doing incorrectly?

Comment: "doesn't work" (or "can't get it to work") doesn't really tell us anything. It doesn't do what you want when you run it, but what _does_ it do?

Comment: Also, `sed -i ''` is BSD usage. On Linux, leave out the `''`. And lookbehind assertions don't generally work in `sed` (which is expected to only support POSIX BRE out-of-the-box, with POSIX ERE enabled when using `-r` or `-E` flags, whereas lookahead and lookbehind are a PCRE extension, not part of _either_ BRE or ERE standards) -- make sure you test your regex _for `sed` specifically_, not in other tools..

Comment: Anyhow, if the problem _is_ specifically with `sed`, it would be helpful if you factored out the `find` parts to narrow it. For that matter, if it's not a problem specifically with the `-i` flag, factor that out too. The simplest reproducer for the `sed` problem with backrefs would just be `sed -e -e 's/(?<=css)([\?%3F]).*(?=")//g' <<'EOF'`, then your data, then `EOF`.

Comment: (BTW, you don't _need_ lookbehind for this sed expression; you should be able to rewrite it using just backreferences to reinsert the content you want to match but not delete on the replace side).

Comment: The character class `[\?%3F]` doesn't need the backslash and does match any one of `?`, `%`, `3` or `F` — it does not require `%3F` to be consecutive characters.  If your regexes support look-behind, they support `(\?|%3F)` which looks for a question mark (and the backslash is probably needed now) or `%3F`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy great point about ```sed -i ' '``` being BSD. I am testing this out on OS X but plan to deploy it to a build script running on Ubuntu. Right now, when I run the code with the regex I wrote nothing is matched. If I change the text to be exact, e.g., 's/?v=7c55ebffcc//g' then the file is updated as expected so the find command is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't do what you think it should be doing. Try this one `'s/^(.*\.css)[^"]+(".*)/\1\2/g'`

```
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/built/screen.css?v=7c55ebffcc" />
' | sed -r 's/^(.*\.css)[^"]+(".*)/\1\2/g'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/built/screen.css" />
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/built/screen.css%3Fv=b45eadba8e.css" />
> ' | sed -r 's/^(.*\.css)[^"]+(".*)/\1\2/g'
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/built/screen.css" />
```

Note the use of `-r` with GNU sed for extended regex.

Comment: For portability, POSIX option `-E` should be used instead of `-r`.  Also the `sed` command can be simplified to `'s/^(.*\.css)[^"]+/\1/'` in this use case.